# setText() not working

Tags: android, android-layout, settext

setText(), setTextsize() and addView is not working. It is shown as cannot resolve symbol type.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
layout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: check if message string is empty ? , and relative layout's width and height is set properly .

Answer (score 1):

You can't use methods such as **add** and **find view by id** before the layout is inflated. Verifý that setContentView is called before.

If it does, look at the value of *message* with a log.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed this

```
``
```

At the end of this line

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);``
```

Comment: sorry. it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textView;
{
     textView = new TextView(this);
     textView.setTextSize(40);
     textView.setText(message);
}

RelativeLayout layout;
{
     layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
     layout.addView(textView);
}
```

this solved my errors.