# Android set.text not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Set.text not working in my adapter.
line 66 http://paste.ubuntu.com/24478136/

My opinions;
i'm using sliderview in this xml probably sliderview calling the default layout so settext not working.
i find these also, but i could not make it

**  There is no error, it just not working. doesnt set the text. **

[android TextView setText not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347016/android-textview-settext-not-working)

[setText() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330411/settext-not-working)

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: There is no error it just not working. doesnt set the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getView()` method why you can inflate view twice.You can inflate view only 1 time,so remove satirView and return just view:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
```

And

```
satirView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
```

Remove the last satirView and return the only view.